# Can't get Pi 4 8gb to boot Octopi

Tags: boot

Followed the tutorial using the Raspberry Pi Imager and installed the latest Octopi O/S onto first a Sandisk 64gb card then a 32gb Sandisk card
Both flashed green a few times on and off then the red light remained static red throughout!
in Windows I opened up a browser and typed in octopi. Local. but it wont find the Pi4

Comment: I have also tried the EEPROM Bootloader on both sd cards then reinstalled Octopi but still flashing a green light a few times then just a solid red light throughout!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm new to Raspberry Pi and wanted to setup Octopi but after powering on the Pi the Green light flashes on and off at different intervals for about 10 seconds then nothing but the Red static light and i tried to find it on my network but nothing is showing!

Comment: take note of the pattern of flashes - i.e COUNT them - number of short, number of long etc ... this is debugging info

Comment: I'm not sure what happend but i reformatted the 32gb SD card from the Installer then re-flashed the Octoprint onto the SD card then searched for Octopi.local on my network which popped up now it's connected!